# Cannot see status of redirect: manual fetch

Tags: fetch

I am using fetch to get information.  When I do the following:

```
fetch('http://somedomain.com/something', { redirect: 'manual' }).then(console.log);
```

I get a [response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) with a status of 0.  I would like to know if the status was a 301 or 302.  Is there any way to determine this?

NOTE: for the purpose of this question assume all requests are within my domain and not cross origin.